# What is the difference between these two output.path webpack configurations?

Tags: webpack

What is the difference between using `path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')` and `./dist` in the `output.path` webpack configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If your `webpack.config.js` is in the base folder of your code, then they are likely to produce the same result.

### Just using `.dist` folder:

It means Webpack will emit the output in this `process.cwd() + 'dist'` folder. `process.cwd()` returns the **current working directory**.

Scenario 1:

- `Webpack.config.js` Path: `c:\work\project\scripts\webpack.config.js`
- Command executed: `webpack --config scripts\webpack.config.js`
- Command executed from: `c:\work\project`
- Output directory: `c:\work\project\dist\**`

Scenario 1:

- `Webpack.config.js` Path: `c:\work\project\scripts\webpack.config.js`
- Command executed: `webpack --config scripts\webpack.config.js`
- Command executed from: `c:\work\project\scripts`
- Output directory: `c:\work\project\scripts\dist\**`

### Using path.resolve():

Whereas using `path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')` means Webpack will emit the output in the `__dirname + './dist'` folder. `__dirname` is the module level global variable in Node.js that returns the directory name of the current module.

It means if the path of your `Webpack.config.js` is `c:\work\project\scripts\webpack.config.js`, then Webpack will produce the dist folder at this path: `c:\work\project\scripts\dist\**`. It doesn't matter from where you execute the Webpack command.